# Bash: How to do decimal number division?

Tags: bash

$num=12.53

How can I divide by 5 and get a decimal result in bash script?

$(($num/5)) doesn't work.

Comment: Use `bc` or something else.  `bash` doesn't support floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kent$  num=12.53

kent$  echo "scale=2;$num/5"|bc
2.50

kent$  awk -v n="$num" 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f\n", n/5}'
2.51
```

note the `bc`'s `scale` and `printf`'s format may give different result.

Answer (score 4):

BASH doesn't support decimal point arithmetic. You need to use `bc` or `awk`:

```
num=12.53
bc -l <<< "scale=2; $num/5"
2.50
```

OR using awk:

```
awk -v n=$num 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", (n/5)}'
```